# Eclipse Memory Analyzer - Incompatible JVM

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, eclipse-mat

I have download [Eclipse MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/mat/1.12.0/rcp/MemoryAnalyzer-1.12.0.20210602-win32.win32.x86_64.zip) and try to launch it on Windows.

Executing `MemoryAnalyzer.exe` display a popup **Incompatible JVM** with this message: *Version 1.8.0_242 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required*.

As said in this [doc](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM), I have created a `jre` directory and copied an OpenJDK 16 which solves the issue.

But I don't find this solution very elegant. So I tried to add the `-vm` parameter in the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` and also tried to create an `eclipse.ini` file as reference by the doc. It doesn't work !

**Is there a way to configure the location of the JVM without copy it entirely in the mat/jre directory ?**

- **NB 1:** the documentation seems out of date. The `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` file exists whereas the doc references the `eclipse.ini` which is not present in the default installation.
- **NB 2:** I don't want to change my `JAVA_HOME` just for this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said previously, one solution is to create a `jre` directory and copy a JDK in it.

Answer (score 6):

The `-vm` parameter in MemoryAnalyzer.ini does work, use two lines for `-vm` and the path to the JVM.
The documentation explaining about eclipse.ini is general Eclipse documentation; Memory Analyzer is an RCP application with its own command, so uses a different ini file. See also [Problems Starting the Memory Analyzer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#java.lang.RuntimeException:_No_application_id_has_been_found.)

Comment: Using two lines for -vm and the path to the JVM doesn't work for me. Incompatible error still shows up. Two lines are `-vm
` and `"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin"`. I have to run `MemoryAnalyzer.exe -vm "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin"` from command line. Not sure why?

Comment: Make sure the -vm arguments are before any -vmargs lines. The -vmargs lines must come last. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for general documentation for eclipse.ini files; for memory analyzer the file is called MemoryAnalyzer.ini

Comment: It works. Thank you. The wiki link is helpful. By the way, the two lines have to be `-vm`  and `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin`. The second line cannot be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

example of MemoryAnalyzer.ini:

```html
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.700.v20221108-1024
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
-vmargs
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED
-Xmx5024m
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\binjavaw.exe
```